# Write Information to PDF File with Java

Tags: java, pdf

I am currently developing a Java App for a company to help keep track of client records. At some point, some of the client's information is written down in an Order form and then is translated to several PDF documents. I noticed with PDF's in Adobe Acrobat Reader that input fields have values that can be stored or re-written. I was wondering if it was possible to write information to these input fields with Java? Or if anyone would have any idea of how to do such a feature?

I've seen this done with PHP so I assume it's a similar process in which I would just have to write and translate information from the order form to the input fields. I don't want to spend time recreating the entire PDF file in Java so I was wondering if there were perhaps a way I can access the info through the use of an object or something. Or some kind of hack I don't know about yet....

Comment: *"I did do a decent amount of research"* - You did not. Considering your comment to Artion's answer you knew about iText and pdfbox but did not care to visit the examples on their respective web sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iText or Apache PDFBox to read your PDFs and write your content.

Comment: I saw this however the only thing I found was a site that could convert the PDF. What I need is to be able to do it with Java. I'm using Netbeans.

Comment: I noticed that iText helps you create a PDF but how do I write information to a PDF that already exists?

Comment: Im sure the guys at iText offer something to manipulate an existing PDF file. They got a large documentation and examples for every case